# How do I add a C# Azure Function App an Azure Resource Group Project for deployment

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

How do I add a C# Azure Function App that I have created in my Visual Studio 2017 solution to an Azure Resource Group Project and have it deploy to Azure. The ultimate goal here is I have a WebApp that is a website but I want to use an Azure Function App as a backend. This would require two separate projects but I want them to publish at the same time which lead me to Azure Resource Group projects. I was able to successfully deploy the Resource Group when it was only the WebApp but once I added the Function App it fails to build. I feel like this whole process should be a lot simpler.

Comment: If you want a devops style of doing things something like [octopus deploy](https://octopus.com/)

Comment: Can you share your ARM template ? what is the part that fail ? do you want to push the function app + the web app as artefact of the ARM template ? Yeah ocotpus or VSTS are great solution to automte youre deployment

Answer (score 1):

Created a issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/733) to track adding support to deploy via Azure Resource Group project.